# Auth functionality not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This appears to have been asked before, however none of the suggested methods in those posts have resolved the issue for me.

What I have done so far:

1. Have run `make:auth` command, which has created the `auth` subfolder, controllers and has added the line `Auth::routes();` to `web.php`, among other things.
2. `@guest` line in `app.blade.php` works correctly and shows Login, Register links in the navbar.
3. The login link reads like this:

   ```
   <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
   ```

   This line correctly launches 'http://localhost/MyWebsite/public/login' but instead of showing default Login page content, it shows Laravel error page saying **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found**.
4. `LoginController`'s constructor gets hit when I load I load index page.
5. `route list` command shows the following route among several others:

   ```
   GET|HEAD    login   login   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm web,guest
   ```
6. I have made multiple modifications to `.htaccess` file, copying the content from different accepts answers on SO. I have also tried empty `.htaccess` file.
7. I have run `config:cache` and `view:clear` commands too.

Are there any other things anyone would suggest?

I'm using VSCode + XAMPP + Laravel 5.6. I have run migrations correctly on MySQL database and have got `users` table created.

Comment: Your docroot should be the public directory, it seems you are currently one above. The route login likely will match if the URL is only /login then.

Comment: Yeah. In fact I live two levels down from localhost. My full path is `localhost/MyWebsite/public`. Even if I remove `MyWebsite`, the `public` folder will still be there since this is from Laravel. What should I change in my routing so that it refers to the correct folder?

Comment: this sounds that csrf token is missing on your page content.

Comment: There should be a setting in your Apache conf named `DocumentRoot` you can adjust. I always find it more convenient to create an extra `VirtualHost` per project with a `ServerName` like *projectxy.local* rather than putting projects in subdirectories, though.

Comment: @TobiasK: You're one good man. This solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Great. I added it as an answer if your want to approve that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docroot should be the *public* directory, it seems you are currently one above. The route `login` likely will match if the URL is only */login* then.

There should be a setting in your Apache conf named `DocumentRoot` you can adjust.